# how can select 3 records of foreign key with join in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm sorry for my poor English . 
I have a table for project registration : like

```
Type of service | Total Amount | prepayment | last payment  | Cost of tolls 
   web design   |      1000    |  1 (F-key) |  2 (F-key)    |   3 (F-key)
```

The second table for the status of payment and amount

```
  id   |  amount  |   Payment status  |    Description
  1    |   400    |        yes        |   for prepayment  
  2    |   600    |        no         |   for last payment 
  3    |    0     |        no         |   for Cost of tolls
```

Now my question is : How can I join two tables And pull out all THAT three columns ?

I've pulled out the prepayment column with this code

```
SELECT mzmx_request.service, mzmx_request.amount,
(mzmx_payment.payment) as prepayment,
(mzmx_payment.status) as prepayment_status 
FROM mzmx_request
JOIN mzmx_payment ON mzmx_request.prepayment = mzmx_payment.id
```

How do I add two more columns?

```
JOIN mzmx_payment ON mzmx_request.payment = mzmx_payment.id
JOIN mzmx_payment ON mzmx_request.pay_more = mzmx_payment.id
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join three times. You already did it once. For example:

```
SELECT
  r.service, 
  r.amount,
  pp.payment as prepayment,
  pp.status as prepayment_status,
  lp.payment as last_payment,
  lp.status as last_payment_status,
  ct.payment as cost_of_tolls,
  ct.status as cost_of_tolls_status 
FROM mzmx_request r
left JOIN mzmx_payment pp ON r.prepayment = pp.id
left JOIN mzmx_payment lp ON r.lastpayment = lp.id
left JOIN mzmx_payment ct ON r.costoftolls = ct.id
```

Since you are joining three times against the same table you'll need to alias the table. In this case I used the aliases `pp`, `lp`, and `ct` for prepayment, last payment, and cost of tolls respectively.

Answer (score 0):

3 referenced fields are independent - so they needs in independent ref table copies:

```
SELECT *
FROM main
JOIN slave AS slave1 ON main.prepayment    = slave1.id
JOIN slave AS slave2 ON main.last_payment  = slave2.id
JOIN slave AS slave3 ON main.cost_of_tolls = slave3.id
```